# How to avoid the crendetial dialog box while conecting to different system using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am making connection to the diferent system using powershell. I want this process to be automated in a way that once user hits the powershell script he gets connected to different system without entering username and password details into the dialog box. So, currently my.PS1 script as follows:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts CP0001256
Restart-Service WinRM
Test-WsMan CP0001256
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path "D:\$Env:USERNAME_pass.xml"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName CP0001256-ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem D:\ }-credential $credential
```

Before running my.PS1 i have executed follwing script:

```
$credential = Get-Credential  
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path "D:\$Env:USERNAME_pass.xml"
```

So, when i execute my.PS1 i got error as:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. username
At my.PS1:7 char 86
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName CP0001256-ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem D:\ } -credential <<<< $credential
     + CategoryInfo         : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindin..mationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorID : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.InvokeCommand
```

So, tell me what i am doing wrong and how can i avoid getting the credential dialog box pop up appearing.

Comment: Looking at your edit, did you enter a user name in the prompt when the dialog came up for you to save your credentials?

Comment: Yes, in the dialog i did entered username as well as password.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of how to store credentials in a script. Keep in mind that this always carries some risk. You can of course store them in plain text. Then anyone with access to the script has those credentials.

Another thing you can do is take advantage of the `[PSCredential]` object, and store the password encrypted. Consider running this code (outside of that script):

```
$credential = Get-Credential  # dialog pops up here, enter server creds
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path "C:\Script\$Env:USERNAME_Credential.xml"
```

Now in your script, you can do this:

```
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path "C:\Script\$Env:USERNAME_Credential.xml"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName CP0001256-ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem D:\ }-credential $credential
```

The password is encrypted within that XML file, and it's encrypted with a key that is specific to the user who ran the first set of commands, so only that user will be able to effectively run the script if you do this.

This is also why I use the `USERNAME` environment variable as part of the file name. You can have multiple employees run the first code snippet to generate a separate encrypted file for each of them. Then your script will work successfully when any of them run it.

It also works if you have an account used for a scheduled task for example; run the snippet as that user once, then the scheduled task will work.

Comment: I did as you said but that credential dialog box still popping up.:(. I dont want that to apear.

Comment: What i did is firstly executed $credential = Get-Credential  # dialog pops up here, enter server creds
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path "C:\Script\$Env:USERNAME_Credential.xml" and then in my.PS1 i added second code snipet and got error as "cannot process argument transformation on parameter  'Credential'.username"

Comment: @anamikaemail I would need to see exactly what you put in the second part, that error doesn't make much sense to me. Can you edit your question to include the new code?

Comment: i have updated the question now..you may check it now

Comment: I think you want `"C:\Script\$($Env:USERNAME)_Credential.xml"` rather than `"C:\Script\$Env:USERNAME_Credential.xml"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen should not be necessary. At least not on 3+. Maybe on 2.0, actually, in which case one could also use `"C:\Script\${Env:USERNAME}_Credential.xml"`. I thought about it but the error message just doesn't seem right for this because it's referencing the call to `Invoke-Command`, not the line where `Import-CliXml` is used (which is where that would cause a problem presumably).

Comment: @briantist unless an environment named "USERNAME_Credential" already exist, you're effectively exporting to `C:\Scripts\.xml`. `_` will (unlike `-`) be parsed as part of variable name